# Postgresql C function that takes a FLOAT8[] and returns an INT[]?

Tags: c, arrays, postgresql

Could someone please provide a template for a C function that would receive FLOAT8[] values and return INT[] values?

The examples that I have found use the same input numeric type as the output numeric type.

I have not seen any examples that show how to create a new INT[] and return it.

Comment: Please edit your question and answer:  By 'INT[]', do you really mean 'int[]'?  Can you define what you mean by 'FLOAT8'?

Comment: Note that a built-in cast function does this already: `select ('{1.0,2.1,3.0}'::float[])::int[]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return an array from a Postgres C function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557980/return-an-array-from-a-postgres-c-function)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
INT *my_function1(FLOAT8 *float8)
   {
   INT *zzz = malloc(sizeof(INT) * 10);

   zzz[0] = 123;
   zzz[1] = 234;
   ...

   return(zzz);
   }
```

Call the above like this:

```
{
INT    *aaa = NULL;
FLOAT8  bbb[10];

...


aaa = my_function1(bbb);
printf("%d, %d\n", aaa[0], aaa[1]);  /* Output: "123, 234"

...

if(aaa)
   free(aaa);

}
```

---

Another way:

```
void my_function2(FLOAT8 *IN_float8, INT **OUT_int)
   {
   INT *yyy=malloc(sizeof(INT) * 10);

   zzz[0] = 123;
   zzz[1] = 234;
   ...

   if(OUT_int)
      *OUT_int = yyy;
   else
      {
      free(yyy);
      fprintf(stderr, "Oops!  You gave me a NULL pointer for OUT_int.\n");
      }

   return;
   }
```

Call the above like this:

```
{
INT    *aaa = NULL;
FLOAT8  bbb[10];

...


my_function1(bbb, &aaa);
printf("%d, %d\n", aaa[0], aaa[1]);  /* Output: "123, 234"

...

if(aaa)
   free(aaa);

}
```